# I want to fetch the username of the logged in user and set it as a default value for an input field

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am fetching username from a collection called users and want to make it the initial value of an input field and then resubmit into another collection called usersPost in mongoDB. Below are the lines of codes I have written.

```
  const [nme, setNme] = useState('');
```

The lines of codes below is used to fetch userData from my API

```
   const getUser = () => {
    axios.get('/api/users')
    .then((response) => {
      setUsers(response.data)
    })
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getUser()
  }, [])
```

I can get the username appear as a value in the input field. The challenge I have is that when I submit the form, an empty field is sent to the database except I trigger the onChange function by typing in the input field. What I want to achieve is sending the logged in user's username into the database and fetch it with every post the user makes on the app.

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                  
                  {users.length > 0 && (
                  <span>
                    {users.map(user => (
                      <span key={user._id}>
                        <input 
                            onChange={event => setNme(event.target.value)}                             
                            type="text"
                            value={user.username}
                        />             
                      </span>                      
                    ))}
                  </span>
                  )}               

                <button> Post </button>                   
</form>
```

Looking forward for your help please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see you're trying to use controlled form components but there is an error in the way you trying to do it. When you're using controlled form components in an input field, the value needs to be the state value in order to React render the updated value when it changes.

I also see that you're rendering multiples user's input, in this case each user needs to have their own state, I recommend you to save an array of the `users` object into a state called users and pass an `id` to a custom function update a specific user.

*this is not the most performatic way to do it, but it is one way, I hope it helps you*

**Example below**

```js
function Test() {

    // value from api
    const APIUsers = [
        { id: 'abc-xxx', name: 'jhonatan' },
        { id: 'acc-xxx', name: 'Luana' },
    ]
   // recommend using the UUID library for dynamic id creation

    // States
    const [users, setUsers] = useState()

    // Getters
    function getUser() {
        // get the users
        setUsers(APIUsers)
    };

    // Handlers
    function handleUserNameUpdate(userID, name) {

        // below we pass through the users array and verify if the user in the loop is the edited user return a new object updating the user data if not return the user, in this way the user stay in the same position in the array and always with the updated data
        // if you have any problem trying to understand this i recommend you to read about Imutability and controlled and uncontrolled form component
        const updatedUsers = users.map(user => {
            if (user.id === userID) {
                return ({
                    ...user,
                    name
                })
            }
            return user
        })

        setUsers(updatedUsers) // update the users list
    }

    // Effects
    useEffect(() => {
        getUser()
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            {users && users.map(user => (
                <input
                    onChange={event => handleUserNameUpdate(user.id, event.target.value)}
                    type="text"
                    value={user.name}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```